# Is the "CHANGE" command in sql a DML or DDL command?

Tags: sql

in the command change column name ... is change used as dml command?

there was a question to list dml commands in a test , i had given change as an example but i havent seen it being a dml command :| ...
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE <column_name> <new_column_name> <data_type> ..

Comment: What `CHANGE` command?

Comment: ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE <column_name> <new_column_name> <data_type> ..

Comment: @DVS_181204 that would be the ALTER TABLE command.

Comment: so change is not an sql command?

Comment: No it is a keyword (In MySQL) in the grammar for the `ALTER TABLE` command